# Android - Supporting a tablet only app on phones

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have an app which is supported currently only on tablets (Honeycomb+). A typical screen in the app has 2 fragments in a activity just like a news reader app. Fragment A's click will show the appropriate content in Fragment B. Now the question is, How do I support this app on phones (Froyo+)? This is just the opposite of supporting fragments from activities. Any kind of help/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this: 
[image]

- Create a layout, one for a handset and one for a tablet.

**layout/main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/handset"
[...]
>
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout-large/sw400dp:**

```
<LinearLayout 
  [...]
  >

    <fragment android:name="com.bla.bla.FirstFragment"
              android:id="@+id/first_fragment"
              [...]
              />

     <fragment android:name="com.bla.bla.SecondFragment"
              android:id="@+id/second_fragment"
              [...]
              />

</LinearLayout>
```

- Now check for this in your FragmentActivity:

---

```
if (findViewById(R.id.handset) != null) {
    // it's a handset device and you can add a Fragment to this View
    }

 FirstFragment firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.handset, firstFragment).commit();
```

- if `R.id.handset` returns null then it's a tablet, in this case the statically added Fragments will be handled by their Fragments class.

Answer (score 0):

On phones, every click that updated fragments on tablets will launch a new activity that contains this fragment.

That's more or less the only thing to do : 
* encapsulating less fragment in one activity, often one fragment
* linking those new activities together.

Your activities will just be a new glue and you will reuse fragments.

Also, take care of communication between fragments within the tablet app, you will have to move part of it in Activities.